# How can I set the URL of a resourceful route?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have a resourceful route called 'pages', with a PagesController and a Page model. I want the show method to be available at http://site.dev/slug instead of http://site.dev/pages/slug. How can I do this in Laravel 5?

I have tried

```
Route::resource('/{slug}', 'PagesController');
```

But that results in the following route list:

```
|        | POST     | {slug}                         | {slug}.store        | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@store            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | {slug}                         | {slug}.index        | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | {slug}/create                  | {slug}.create       | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@create           |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | {slug}/{{slug}}                | {slug}.show         | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@show             |            |
|        | PUT      | {slug}/{{slug}}                | {slug}.update       | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@update           |            |
|        | PATCH    | {slug}/{{slug}}                |                     | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@update           |            |
|        | DELETE   | {slug}/{{slug}}                | {slug}.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@destroy          |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | {slug}/{{slug}}/edit           | {slug}.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@edit             |            |
```

And the show method returns the error

```
"Route pattern "/{slug}/{{slug}}" cannot reference variable name "slug" more than once."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Route::resource('/{slug}', 'PagesController');` it will attempt to create multiple routes to handle a variety of RESTful actions. Some of those deal with individual objects referred to by an ID. For instance, the "show" method assumes "slug" to be the noun describing a group of objects and then expects an ID to identify a specific one.

I believe you can address this by using an optional route parameter for that ID and choose whether to handle it in your controller methods: `Route::resource('/{slug}/{id?}', 'PagesController');`

Answer (score 0):

Create resource route similar to '/{slug}'.

```
Route::resource('/{slug}', 'MainController');
```

Comment: This produces  "| GET|HEAD | {slug}/{{slug}}                | {slug}.show         | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@show" which throws the error "Route pattern "/{slug}/{{slug}}" cannot reference variable name "slug" more than once."

Comment: Did you try '{slug}'? If you'll not find any good way to you want, you can try standard way for APIs like 'api/{slug}' or just short 'a/{slug}'